# Topics have_many posts. Get all topics without any posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A blog has "topics", "topics" have "posts".

How can I get a count of all topics without posts? So basically unused topics.

```
topics = Topic.all
topics.???
```

Comment: Can you post the associations as well? For example a `post` `belongs to :topic`, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Topic.includes(:posts).where('posts.topic_id is null').references(:posts).count
```

After seeing other answers, I ran both the statements in my console.

This answer generates the following query

```
 (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "topics"."id") FROM "topics" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."topic_id" = "topics"."id" WHERE (posts.topic_id is null)
```

While the other answer generates two queries (as obvious).

```
(0.6ms)  SELECT "posts"."topic_id" FROM "posts"
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "topics" WHERE ("topics"."id" NOT IN (2,3,11,23))
```

Comment: Exactly. This is with only 4 ids in the where statement, and time taken would increase with the number of ids to match with.

Comment: Manoj - I'm not sure what you're trying to say. The where statement seems to only check 1 value for an id - whether it is null or not. Where are you getting the number "4" from?

Answer (score 0):

Topic.where(" id not in ?", Post.pluck(:topic_id))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get all topics without any posts:

```
Topic.where.not(id: Post.pluck(:topic_id))
```